# render of a4j commandButton doesnt work; page not rendering

Tags: jsf, ajax4jsf

when i click the button handler.toggleCreatingTheme() is called, but the outputPanel is not rendering. When i refresh the page(f5) the content of the panel is showed.

```
                <a4j:commandButton styleClass="simple-submit-button"
                    action="#{handler.toggleCreatingTheme()}"
                    rendered="#{!handler.creatingTheme}"
                    value="txt"
                    immediate="true"
                    render="newThemeForm" oncomplete="initEditor()" status="statusWait" />

                <a4j:outputPanel id="newThemeForm" ajaxRendered="true" rendered="#{handler.creatingTheme}">
```

this tags are both in a h:form tag, there is just that one h:form.

How do I let the page refreshing on his own, so rendering the panel at the moment when i click the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embed `newThemeForm` within another a4j:outputPanel and render it instead of reRendering `newThemeForm`.This is because `newThemeForm` will not be in DOM when trying to render it as it's `rendered` attribute will still be `false`.
Like:

```
<a4j:outputPanel id="outerPanel>
<a4j:outputPanel id="newThemeForm" rendered="#{bean.booleanvalue}">
</a4j:outputPanel>
</a4j:outputPanel>
```

Render `outerPanel` and not the `newThemeForm`.

Answer (score 0):

i have tried the way that AhamedMustafaM mentioned but it didnt work with me , so i searched and tried for a little while so finally i got to make it work with a workaround, here is how

```
<a4j:commandButton id="clear" value="Clear" action="#{handler.clearData}"  immediate="true"  >
    <!-- dummy call just to make it work -->
    <a4j:actionListener listener="#{ViewerController.test}"/>
    <f:ajax render="dataGroupPanel"/>
</a4j:commandButton>
```